# Does HPX provide a task-based parallelized iteration function with grain size control?

Tags: c++, hpx

Does HPX provide any sort of parallelized iteration function built on top of [task-based fork-join parallelism](http://stellar.cct.lsu.edu/files/hpx-1.0.0/html/hpx/manual/parallel/task_block.html) that also lets you control the grain size used? similar to TBB's [parallel_for](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506153) or Cilk's [cilk_for](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/522593).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does. We implemented some extensions to what the standardization committee is contemplating about. HPX has introduced the concept of `ExecutorParameters` which amongst other things allow to control the grain-size of the parallelization of iterations. For instance:

```
std::vector<int> v = { ... };
hpx::parallel::static_chunk_size scs;
hpx::parallel::for_each(
    hpx::parallel::execution::par.with(scs),
    v.begin(), v.end(),
    [](int val) { ... }
);
```

This will split the iterations into tasks of `(num_iterations / 4 * cores)` loop iterations. You can also specify the size of the tasks:

```
hpx::parallel::static_chunk_size scs(100);
```

which will combine 100 iterations in each task.

Other existing executor parameters are for instance `dynamic_chunk_size` (similar to openmp's `schedule(dynamic)`), and `guided_chunk_size` (similar to openmp's `schedule(guided)`), etc.